# Fast-ClassPath-Scanner does not work with java 6 runtime?

Tags: java, reflection

Fast-ClassPath-Scanner 
https://github.com/lukehutch/fast-classpath-scanner using latest version.
On executing(get names of all classes in war which includes all jars and classes)

```
new FastClasspathScanner(basePackage).scan().getNamesOfAllClasses()
```

getting:

> unsupportedclassversion error with jre 6

Please provide a solution to it or alternative to perform same.

Answer (score 0):

FastClasspathScanner is compiled for java 1.7

When you try to load it in a 1.6 (JRE6) environment it fails with an `UnsupportedClassVersionError`. This error indicates that the class version (here 1.7) is not compatible with the JVM version (here 1.6).

Java 7 is not backwards compatible with Java 6. You could try to build the FastClasspathScanner library yourself unter 1.6 (not sure if that's possible). Or upgrade your project to Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, I am the author of FastClasspathScanner, and it's not a goal to get this working with JRE6. However, patches for supporting 1.6 are welcome.

Comment: hi! any tip regarding [coupling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097780/how-to-show-class-dependencies-with-fast-classpath-scanner)?